# SAP Script Recording and Playback - Cumulative data

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

If I am using the Script Recording and Playback feature on same transaction for instance `ME25`, multiple times, I am getting cumulative data as part of multiple scripts rather than incremental data.

Explanation : 
If I open `ME25` details and enter "100-310" as Material and "Ball Bearing" as Short Text and stop the recording, I get the following script, which is expected behavior.
[image: SAP Recording 1]

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/ctxtEBAN-MATNR[3,0]").text = "100-310"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/txtEBAN-TXZ01[4,0]").text = "Ball Bearing"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/txtEBAN-TXZ01[4,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/txtEBAN-TXZ01[4,0]").caretPosition = 12
```

After this, I restart the recording and type Qty Requested as "100" and delivery date as "21.04.2021" and stop the recording. [image: SAP Recording 2] I get the following script:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/ctxtEBAN-MATNR[3,0]").text = "100-310"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/txtEBAN-TXZ01[4,0]").text = "Ball Bearing"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/txtEBAN-MENGE[5,0]").text = "100"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/ctxtRM06B-EEIND[8,0]").text = "21.04.2021"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/ctxtEBAN-EKGRP[9,0]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMM06BTC_0106/ctxtEBAN-EKGRP[9,0]").caretPosition = 0
```

Instead of getting the incremental part that I typed for the second recording instance, I am getting complete script. Is there a way to achieve incremental scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce in my SAP GUI 7.60 (whatever screen it is; whatever kind of field it is, I can reproduce even with very simple fields like in a Selection Screen).

It seems that it happens all the time, even if you write your own recorder (a VBS script which mainly uses `session.record = True` + event handlers). It's due to the fact that SAP GUI sends all the screen events (i.e. the user actions) since the screen was entered, when the user presses a button, a function key, closes a window, or stops the SAP GUI Recorder.

If you write your own recorder, I guess you can save the screen contents when you start the recorder, and when the "change" events occur you may ignore those ones where the new field value has not changed since the recorder started. But that's a lot of work.

I think that it's far more easy to append manually the last lines of the last script to the initial script.